# "Error 403: access_denied" when usign Google OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, whmcs

I am trying to understand the basic logics for receiving GMail emails with Google OAuth. I see this document [Authorizing Your App with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth)

Now I follow the instructions in [Setting Up POP3 Importing with OAuth via Google](https://help.whmcs.com/m/support_tools/l/1328652-setting-up-pop3-importing-with-oauth-via-google) to setup POP3 with Google OAuth.

I login one Google account(Account1) and then in Google Cloud, create the Google App and OAuth Client ID.

Then I start connect to GMail account(Account2) with the web application(WHMCS). When connecting, it asks me to choose an account that create the app, so I choose Account1. But get the following error:

> Error 403: access_denied
> The developer hasn’t given you access to this app.

Thus I am a bit confused. Since Account1 is used to create the app and OAuth Client ID, it **should be able to access the app** when I choose Account1, but the app will not be able to access the data in Account2. Or does the **App** in the error message means **Gmail**, not **the app** I created in Google Cloud?

Should I use Account2 to create the app for receiving emails in Account2? If yes, then for each Gmail account, should I create a separate app accordingly?

**Update**

Now I try to do as follows:

1. Use Account3(The admin of Google Workspace) to create the Cloud Project, Consent Window, Client ID, etc.
2. Then when connecting from WHMCS on our domain datanumen.com, it asks me to choose the account, I choose Account3, and then see a new window as below:

[image]

I then select "Allow" button, but then see the following error:

**Connection unsuccessful. Please close this window and try again.**

**Update**

I try several times. And find the first time will be successful. I forget enable POP3 in my Gmail account. After enabling it, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to do here.

You created a project on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard) and created client id and client secret for the authorization of your project.

All this does is create a project that will be allowed to use Oauth2 to request authorization of a user to access their data.

If I understand what [WHMCS](https://help.whmcs.com/m/support_tools/l/1328652-setting-up-pop3-importing-with-oauth-via-google) is trying to do.  Its going to let you use your client id and client secret to request access of a user to access their data.

So when it asks you to authorize a user this is the user whos data you want access to.   That user must be added as a test user over on Google cloud console for the project that you created.

[image]

The project you create on google cloud console is still in the testing phase. Each user you want to allow to test your application must be added as a test user.  Other wise only the owner of the project can test the applicaiton.

To fix this issue for me was this simple:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/
2. open the project in question.
3. Click "OAuth consent screen" on the left.
4. Under "Test users" there is a button called "+ ADD USERS"
5. Type the email of the account you will be testing with, press enter, then click save.
6. It should work now

It seems like they updated this recently because last year I did not have to do this.

## workspace

The issue you may be having is that if you created this project on a workspace account then i suspect only workspace domain users are going to be able to authorize it.   It cant be authorized by someone on the standard google domain.  So try with a workspace domain user.   The same may go the other way I have never tried tbh. I tend to keep workspace within its domain.

Comment: I have followed your instructions but still failed. I just wonder, since I need to access the email data of Account2, there should be a consent from Account2. But in all the steps, there are no such action? Add email of Account2 does not mean Account2 permits you to access his data.

Comment: The developer hasnt given you access to this app means that the user logging in doesnt have permission and needs to be added as a user.  When running your app its only going to give you access to that users data.  Unless you are using a google workspace account and configure domain wide delegation with a service account.

Comment: The Account2 is a WOrkspace user account. The Account1 is a standard account.

Comment: Okay try the edit.   See if this helps

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I use Workspace Admin account(Account3) to create the project and then it seems something is working, but the final step still fails.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It is due to I forget enable POP3 for my Gmail account. Now everything is fine. THank you very much!

Comment: Thats wonderful glad you got it working.  Interesting use case you have there i will need to remember that for the future.

Comment: Sorry for one more question. It seems that create the consent window & client ID in a project is not free? When I access the Google Cloud Console, it offers me 300 USD free credit and then ask my credit card info.

Comment: Its free to create the project.   Some of the cloud apis are not free and cost you to use.  That's what the free cloud time off is for you shouldn't need it for what you are doing.